# multiplication tables in c++ using for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

In c++ I want output to be 6,12,18,24…60. that too while using for loop only and so I did my code but I am getting the output of infinite 6,6,6,6,6,…

my code is

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 /*Table of 6 using For loop*/
 for (int i = 6; i <= 60; i+6)     
 {  
     cout<<i<<endl; 
 } 
 

 return 0;
}
```

the output i want

```
6
12
18
24
30
36
42
48
54
60
```

the output i get

```
6
6
6
6
6
6
∞
```

upto infinty

i dont what my problem is but i do want a solution

Comment: `i+6` -> `i+=6`;

Comment: whats the value of `i` after `i+6` ?

Comment: `i += 6` you didn't assign

Comment: thanks @Bathsheba for giving the correct answer please tell me how this code worked

Comment: @VedantDomadiya: `i += 6` adds `6` to `i`. `i + 6` is an expression equal to `6` added to `i`, but it doesn't change `i`.

Comment: I think this question shoudn't have been closed because even though it is a small typo, it usually happens to a lot of people who are a bit new.

Comment: fwiw, with warnings enabled the code does not compile: https://godbolt.org/z/TEGs67GG4

Comment: @ihsan the thing is that it is almost impossible to make the question searchable. Even if the title was "What happens when I don't increment the loop counter" it is unlikely that future readers will find it when they made the same typo

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 /*Table of 6 using For loop*/
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)     
 {  
     cout<<i*6<<endl; 
 } 
 

 return 0;
}
```

The output from the above program will be:

```
6
12
18
24
30
36
42
48
54
60
```

which is what you want. Also if you replace `i+6` with `i = i + 6` then your for loop will work.